# layout in layout

Tags: cakephp, view, cakephp-2.1

I have a general layout. (`default`)
But for users pages, I should add a panel to each page.

I tried `$this->renderLayout('panel_code', 'default');`, but didn't work; and printed default layout view `view` content! with no `panel_code`!

Where's my mistake?

Comment: it's not possible without `elements`?

Comment: elements are properly created for this scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make elements in `View/Elements` folder with `.ctp` extension.

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) would help you to make clean separation of your view files with the related/repeated code.

An element is basically a mini-view that can be included in other views, in layouts, and even within other elements. Elements can be used to make a view more readable, placing the rendering of repeating elements in its own file. They can also help you re-use content fragments in your application.

Elements live in the /app/View/Elements/ folder, and have the .ctp filename extension. They are output using the element method of the view:

```
<?php echo $this->element('helpbox'); //without extension ?>
```

You can pass variables from your view to the element.

In your view:

```
 <?php echo $this->Element('reviews/view-goal', array('history' => $history));
```

In view-goal.ctp element you can directly access `$history` variable.